# Valor variable se pierde al enviar formulario

Tags: php

**EDITO CON UNA POSIBLE SOLUCIÓN QUE HE ENCONTRADO
En el `action` del form estaba redifigiendo a `687/KILLALLZOMBIES/` con lo cual perdía el valor de la variable `$id_comentario`. Lo he dejado vacío y el problema se ha resuelto. No sé si es la mejor manera pero funcionar funciona bien.**

Estoy trabajando con una variable (entre otras), que recibo a través de la URL. En concreto al entrar a la siguiente URL `687/KILLALLZOMBIES/editar/211/`, el valor de la variable `$id_comentario` sería 211 en este caso. Lo recojo con PHP mediante el siguiente código:

```
$id_comentario = isset($_GET['id_comentario']) ? $_GET['id_comentario'] : "null";
```

He comprobado que al entrar a la URL la variable esté correcta. Mi problema viene cuando envío un formulario, que no es más que un textarea para modificar el comentario. Hay más código que el que os pongo pero ahí se ve que la variable la declaro fuera del condicional if:

```
$id_comentario = isset($_GET['id_comentario']) ? $_GET['id_comentario'] : "null";

if ($conexion and isset($_POST['guardar_edicion'])) {

    $texto = para_vista_previa($_POST['comentario']);
    $texto = evitamos_script($texto);//EVITAMOS SCRIPTS

    $extractos = explode("[", $_POST['comentario']);


    foreach ($extractos as $extracto) {
        if ($pos = strpos($extracto, '/quote') !== false) {
            $total_quotes++;
        }
    }

    $errores = "";

    if (strlen($texto) > 1000) {
        $errores .= "El texto no puede contener más de 1.000 caracteres <br>";
    }

    if ($total_quotes > 3) {
        $errores .= "No puedes tener más de 3 citas en un mismo comentario <br>";
    }

    if (empty($errores)) {

        $quien_comenta = $user;

        $hoy = getdate();
        $meses = ['enero', 'febrero', 'marzo', 'abril', 'mayo', 'junio','julio','agosto','septiembre','octubre','noviembre','diciembre'];

        $minuto = $hoy['minutes'];
        $hora = $hoy['hours'];
        $day = $hoy['mday'];
        $mes = $hoy['mon'];
        $segundos = $hoy['seconds'];

        if ($hoy['hours'] <= 9) {
            $hora = "0" . $hoy['hours'];
        }

        if ($hoy['minutes'] <= 9) {
            $minuto = "0" . $hoy['minutes'];
        }

        if ($hoy['mon'] <= 9) {
            $mes = "0" . $hoy['mon'];
        }

        if ($hoy['mday'] <= 9) {
            $day = "0" . $hoy['mday'];
        }

        if ($hoy['seconds'] <= 9) {
            $segundos = "0" . $hoy['seconds'];
        }

        $fecha_total_actual = $hoy['year'] . "-" . $mes . "-" . $day . " " . $hora . ":" . $minuto . ":" . $segundos;

        //comprobamos si hay menciones
        $resultado = array_unique(obten_menciones($texto));

        foreach ($resultado as $result) {

            if ($result != $_SESSION['usuario']) {
                $statement = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO menciones (de_quien, a_quien, en_que_hilo, foro, subforo, pagina_hilo, tipo, seccion) VALUES (:de_quien, :a_quien, :en_que_hilo, '-', '-', '-', 'mencion', 'noticia')");
                $statement->execute(array(":de_quien" => $_SESSION['usuario'],
                                        ":a_quien" => $result,
                                        ":en_que_hilo" => $en_que_ficha)
                                    );
            }

        }

        $statement = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE comentarios SET texto = :texto, editado_por = :editado_por, fecha_edicion = :fecha_edicion WHERE ID = :id");
        $statement->execute(array(":texto" => $texto,
                                ":editado_por" => $user,
                                ":fecha_edicion" => $fecha_total_actual,
                                ":id" => $id_comentario
                                ));

        //header("Location: " . $ruta . "Juegos/Xbox-One/$en_que_ficha/" . limpia_url($posts[0]['Juego']) . "/");


    }
```

El caso es que al enviar el formulario la variable `$id_comentario` pasa a "null", con lo cual no puedo actualizar el registro de la base de datos. He quitado el redireccionamiento del header (por eso está comentado), y curiosamente en vez de redirigirme `687/KILLALLZOMBIES/`, es decir como si tuviese algún otro redireccionamiento, que ya he mirado, y sólo tengo otro que no afecta. Normalmente suelo encontrar la solución pero no acabo de encontrarla en este caso.

Comment: Los valores enviados no se pierden, el detalle es que no se reciben por indicar una ruta diferente o no saber cómo capturarlos.

Answer (score 1):

El problema era el `action` del form. Lo he solucionado con el siguiente código:

```
<?php

$redirect = "";

if ($metodo == "editar") {
   $redirect = $ruta . "Juegos/Xbox-One/" . $en_que_ficha . "/" . limpia_url($posts[0]['Juego']) . "/editar/" . $id_comentario . "/" ;
} else {
   $redirect = $ruta . "Juegos/Xbox-One/" . $en_que_ficha . "/" . limpia_url($posts[0]['Juego']) . "/" ;
}

?>
<form class="form_comentarios_noticias" action="<?php echo $redirect ?>" method="post">
```